# ExceptionsManager.js:84 Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that look like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {

    state = { albums: [] };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
    }

    renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{album.title}</Text>);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(response.data);
        return <View>{ this.renderAlbums() }</View>;uy
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

This is my entire index.js look like

```
// 1. import library help create a component 
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import AlbumList from './src/components/AlbumList';

// 2. create component 
const App = () => (
    <View>
        <Header headerText={'Albums'}/>
        <AlbumList />
    </View>
)

// 3. render to the device 
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App )
```

When I run my app, I kept getting

```
ExceptionsManager.js:84 Unhandled JS Exception: ReferenceError:
response is not defined

This error is located at:
    in AlbumList (at index.js:11)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)
```

As you can see, I declared it right here

`.then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));`

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error in the `render` method since `response` is not defined there.

```
render() {
    console.log(response.data);
    return <View>{ this.renderAlbums() }</View>;
}
```

Write `this.state.albums` instead.

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.albums);
    return <View>{ this.renderAlbums() }</View>;
}
```

Comment: just for the record, good IDE should detect and report such errors

Comment: I used VSCode, do I need to install anything ? Eslint ?